# SSRS Count Distinct Expression into a Yes or No

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm wondering if there's a way or an expression I could use in SSRS to show a Yes or No based on a Distinct Count function?

Example of what I'm currently using - `RM_Name` is the group

```
=CountDistinct(iif(Fields!qtrtradecnt.Value >= 15, 1, Nothing), "RM_Name")
```

I also would like to show if the `qtrtradecnt is >= 15` to show a Y or N based on the `RM_Name` group, and maybe `countdistinct` is not the correct function to use...I've messed with this for days.

Thank you!

Comment: I would create a calculated field and then do this logic based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to the calculation in your your dataset.. with a case expression..

```
select
...
,case when your_table.qtrtradecnt >= 15 then 1 else 0 end as rm_count 

from your_table
```

Then in your report just do a

> =iif(sum(Fields!rm_count.value) >15 then 'Y','N')